# CakePHP3.x custom validation not working

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Inside UsersTable class, I am trying to implement custom validation following the CakeBook but I got an error saying, `Object of class App\Model\Table\UsersTable could not be converted to string [CORE/src/Validation/ValidationRule.php, line 128]`. Below is my code in UsersTable.php.

```
class UsersTable extends Table{
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator){
        $validator->add(
            "password",[
                 "notEmpty"=>[
                     "notEmpty"
                 ],
                 "custom"=>[
                     "rule"=>[$this,"customFunction"],
                     "message"=>"foo"
                 ]
             ]
        );
    }
    public function customFunction($value,$context){
        //some logic here
    }
}
```

Looking at `ValidationRule.php` in core CakePHP library, I have noticed that `array_shift()` (on line 185) is taking the first element of `[$this,"customFunction"]`, that is, `$this` and assigning it to `$value`. But actually `$value` should be `[$this,"customFunction"]`. Therefore, for my code to work without any error, I needed to add one more nesting to `[$this,"customFunction"]`(So it is now `[[$this,"customFunction"]]`). Do I misunderstand something or is this some kind of bug?

UPD: This problem is now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've spotted that correctly, the problem seems to be that CakePHP expects the `rule` key value to be in

```
[string or callable, ...args]
```

format when it is in array, ie it doesn't test whether the value itself already is a callable.

The documentation says that the non-nested variant should work, so you might want to report this as a bug.

Comment: How can I report this as a bug? on github? Thank you so much for answering my question many times :)

Comment: Ok. I will do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your model for custom validation

```
public function validationCustom($validator)
{
    return $validator
        ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is required');
}
```

Use validation method name except validation keyword in your controller when you want to save or update

```
$user = $this->Articles->newEntity($this->request->data,
        ['validate' => 'custom']);
```